# Why does the automake program seem to have strange lookup precedence on osx?

Tags: macos, unix, path, automake

I have my own program called automake which I originally wrote on an Ubuntu machine and recently wanted to get working on my machine running OSX Lion.

I've compiled it up, copied it into my `/Users/andrew/bin` directory which is one of the first directories listed in my `PATH` variable:

```
bash-3.2$ echo $PATH | tr : '\n'
.
/Users/andrew/bin
/opt/local/bin
/opt/local/sbin
/Users/andrew/Library/Application Support/GoodSync
/Users/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin
/Users/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin
/Users/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin
/Users/andrew/.rvm/bin
.
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/X11/bin
/Users/andrew/.rvm/bin
/Users/andrew/bin
/Users/andrew/.rvm/bin
```

However, when I try to run automake it is clearly running a different automake program. I think it's one of the xcode developer tools:

```
bash-3.2$ automake game.cpp
automake: error: no Automake input file found for 'game.cpp'
automake: error: no input file found among supplied arguments
```

This version of automake is located in `/opt/local/bin`. What I don't understand is how this is possible when my automake is located in an earlier directory in my `PATH` variable. Indeed, the unix `which` program displays the path to my automake:

```
bash-3.2$ which automake
/Users/andrew/bin/automake
```

What sorcery is this?

Answer (score 2):

I spotted two peculiarities in your PATH none of which should be the source of your trouble, but probably you want to correct them anyways

- `/Users/andrew/bin`, `.`  and `/Users/andrew/.rvm/bin` are listed multiple times both of the first ones twice the the third one even three times if I got the counting right.
- your PATH contains `.` Twice even, as mentioned before. From security standpoint that's not be the best idea.

As already stated none of these should be responsible for the problem described. Maybe it could help working on the following questions:

- Are you sure you copied the right file? Not the one of the GNU/autotools automake also lying around on your ubuntu machine?
- Have you tried running *your* automake version by giving an absolute path /Users/andrew/bin/automake?
- Was the output the same as the one you got before or was it different?